# How to address unresponsive redraws and controls with setInterval and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I am developing a simple HTML5 game presently which you can play test at the following URL:

http://frankcaron.com/simplegame/game.html

The code is here:

https://github.com/frankcaron/Personal_HTML5_GamePrototype/blob/master/js/game.js

In order to animate elements, I'm using a few setIntervals. The main game loop has a setInterval which works fine. Some fading elements use them, as well, without issue. The one I'm having an issue with is one for an on-click animation.

The issue I'm having is that, in Safari and also to some extent in Chrome, the click event and animation is not responsive. It doesn't fire every time. I think there is some conflict with the concurrent intervals running. I'm not sure why.

I've done some research on the other method of HTML5 animation using requestAnimFrame but I don't think that'll solve my problem here.

Here is the code of interest:

```
//Track mousedown
addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    //Safari Fix
    e.preventDefault();
    //If you click while the game is going, do your special move
    performSpecial();
}

//Perform a special move
var performSpecial = function () {
    switch(classType)
    {
        case 1:
            //Class 1
            break;
        default:
            //No class
            renderExplosion();
    }
}

//Render explosion special move
var renderExplosion = function () {
    //Temp vars
    var alpha = 1.0;   // full opacity
    var circleMaxRadius = 32;
    fadeCircle = setInterval(function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(hero.x + 16, hero.y + 16, circleMaxRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, " + alpha + ")";
        ctx.stroke();
        circleMaxRadius = circleMaxRadius + 5;
        alpha = alpha - 0.05 ; // decrease opacity (fade out)
        if (alpha < 0) {
            clearInterval(fadeCircle);
        }
    }, 1); 
};
```

Comment: Even if that won't solve this problem, investing some time to learn how to use `rAF` properly will be definitely worth it.

Comment: @FrankCaron Is `classType` ever changed currently?

Comment: @Zeaklous Not currently, no. It will be later, to give each class its own special moves.

Comment: @FrankCaron Have you tried putting alerts in the mousedown function to see if it's firing every time?

Comment: @Zeaklous Yup, and it is. It's definitely seeming like it's an issue with my using too many concurrent intervals in Safari. I think I have to re-engineer the whole thing to use animationFrame.

Comment: My canvas gui WiP project makes use of rAF: http://cssdeck.com/labs/canvasgui . It could be of use I suppose for how you might go about how to format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I rewrote the application using window.requestAnimationFrame and I no longer have this problem. The code is up on my Github if anyone wants to see the full solution.

In brief, I removed all of the intervals and replaced the entire game loop. When an animation effect is needed, I turn a flag on corresponding with the event. The renderer checks this conditional and renders the effect if the flag is on, turning the flag off again when it's done.